# form input select returned as number, not string, with javascript

Tags: javascript, select, input, numbers

I have one **html form** which contain about 5 **select inputs**. Each input has as a value a number. When selection is made, i want to return the value as **number**, and not as a string. Example below:

```
<p>Cop <select name="c_palat" id="c_palat">
  <option value=0>0</option>
  <option value=30>1</option>
  <option value=60>2</option>
</select></p>
 <p>Adult <select name="a_palat" id="a_palat">
  <option value=45>1</option>
  <option value=90>2</option>
  <option value=135>3</option>
</select></p></div>

<script>
    var c_palat = document.getElementById("c_palat");
    var c_pal = c_palat.options[c_palat.selectedIndex].value;
    var a_palat = document.getElementById("a_palat");
    var a_pal = a_palat.options[a_palat.selectedIndex].value;

    var x =c_pal + a_pal

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

So, for a selection of option 1 from first input, (value 0), and option 1 from second input (value 45), the result is **045**(string), not **45**(number).
Thank you for any help provided. Have a nice day.

Comment: Try using `Number(value)`.

Comment: Removing quotes don't make the value a number, you could do the same to string values, the quotes are just needed when there are special characters or spaces in the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Number
This convert the string into a number.

```
<script>
    var c_palat = document.getElementById("c_palat");
    var c_pal = Number(c_palat.options[c_palat.selectedIndex].value);
    var a_palat = document.getElementById("a_palat");
    var a_pal = Number(a_palat.options[a_palat.selectedIndex].value);

    var x =c_pal + a_pal

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse value as integer.

```
var a = parseInt("10") + "<br>";
var b = parseInt("10.00") + "<br>";
var c = parseInt("10.33") + "<br>";
var d = parseInt("34 45 66") + "<br>";
var e = parseInt(" 60 ") + "<br>";
var f = parseInt("40 years") + "<br>";
var g = parseInt("He was 40") + "<br>";

var h = parseInt("10", 10)+ "<br>";
var i = parseInt("010")+ "<br>";
var j = parseInt("10", 8)+ "<br>";
var k = parseInt("0x10")+ "<br>";
var l = parseInt("10", 16)+ "<br>";

var n = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + "<br>" + h + i + j + k +l;
```

Output :

> 10  10  10  34  60  40  NaN 10  10  8  16  16

[Source.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could to with [`parseFloat()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVgqP8-rDUAhUHv48KHXv2A3cQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseFloat&usg=AFQjCNFGjOkpZ1cWnWNYHgjw0eQjZTiL0g&sig2=-rZ6akv1pfvbMFRCsYmuJQ).It convert string to number.And get the selected value with direct method `c_palat.value` instead of `options[c_palat.selectedIndex]`

```js
var c_palat = document.getElementById("c_palat");
var c_pal = parseFloat(c_palat.value);
var a_palat = document.getElementById("a_palat");
var a_pal = parseFloat(a_palat.value);

var x = c_pal + a_pal
console.log(x)
//document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p>Cop <select name="c_palat" id="c_palat">
  <option value=0>0</option>
  <option value=30>1</option>
  <option value=60>2</option>
</select></p>
<p>Adult <select name="a_palat" id="a_palat">
  <option value=45>1</option>
  <option value=90>2</option>
  <option value=135>3</option>
</select></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ~~(double-bitwise not) to convert string to integers only

```js
var c_palat = ~~(document.getElementById("c_palat").value);
var a_palat = ~~(document.getElementById("a_palat").value);

var x = c_palat + a_palat;
console.log(x);
```

```html
<p>Cop <select name="c_palat" id="c_palat">
  <option value=0>0</option>
  <option value=30>1</option>
  <option value=60>2</option>
</select></p>
<p>Adult <select name="a_palat" id="a_palat">
  <option value=45>1</option>
  <option value=90>2</option>
  <option value=135>3</option>
</select></p>
```